# JpaRepository - Hibernate - java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have follow this tutorial https://codingexplained.com/coding/java/spring-framework/return-boolean-value-from-spring-data-jpa-query and there he explain how to return boolean type from a JpaRepository so that is what is did:

```
    @Transactional
    @Override
    @Query(value = "SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN true ELSE false END FROM admins WHERE admins.admin_name = 'admin' AND admins.password = 'admin'", nativeQuery = true)
    boolean IsBaseAdminAccountExist();
```

and this thing is throwing `exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean`

Comment: which database ?

Comment: mysql. does it matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason to use native query here. `select case` is supported in JPQL since JPA 2.0.

Moreover this query is read-only so no need for `@Transactional`.

Try this

```java
    @Override
    @Query(value = "SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN true ELSE false END FROM admins a WHERE a.adminName = 'admin' AND a.password = 'admin'")
    boolean IsBaseAdminAccountExist();
```

I supposed here that admin_name is the column name in db but in your entity the field follows java naming convention `adminName` ...

Comment: thanks it worked but I have one more question before I change it to non-native query it didn't work on MySQL but in my integration tests with H2 database it worked why?

Answer (score 8):

Same error, I share my solution:

When you build your query and cast true or false, it must be enclosed in quotes, like this:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END FROM admins WHERE admins.admin_name = 'admin' AND admins.password = 'admin'", nativeQuery = true)
boolean IsBaseAdminAccountExist();
```

Additionally, I recommend using MYSQL IF condition to simplify your query, it would look like this:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT IF(COUNT(*) > 0, 'true', 'false') FROM admins WHERE admins.admin_name = 'admin' AND admins.password = 'admin'", nativeQuery = true)
boolean IsBaseAdminAccountExist();
```